# Error 18 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _error referenced in function _main

Tags: c

i added this lines to my code and i have this errors:

```
Error   18  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _error referenced in function _main
Error   17  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _bzero referenced in function _main   
Error   19  error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

My code snippet is-

```
else if (strcmp(text, "004") == 0)
                                        {
                                            i = 0;
                                            menuCheck = 1;
                                            puts("Please enter your folder.");
                                            gets(text);
                                            strcpy(folder, COM_MSG);
                                            strcat(folder, "004");
                                            strcat(folder, text);
                                            puts("Please enter your folder for saving.");
                                            gets(fr_name);
                                            if ((temp = send(sock, folder, sizeof(folder), 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                                            {
                                                printf("Error sending connection request to the server, error code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                                            }
                                            /* Receive File from Server */
                                            printf("[Client] Receiveing file from Server and saving it as final.txt...");                                               
                                            FILE *fr = fopen(fr_name, "a");
                                            if (fr == NULL)
                                                printf("File %s Cannot be opened.\n", fr_name);
                                            else
                                            {
                                                bzero(revbuf, 512);
                                                int fr_block_sz = 0;
                                                while ((fr_block_sz = recv(sock, revbuf, 512, 0)) > 0)
                                                {
                                                    int write_sz = fwrite(revbuf, sizeof(char), fr_block_sz, fr);
                                                    if (write_sz < fr_block_sz)
                                                    {
                                                        error("File write failed.\n");
                                                    }
                                                    bzero(revbuf, 512);
                                                    if (fr_block_sz == 0 || fr_block_sz != 512)
                                                    {
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                if (fr_block_sz < 0)
                                                {
                                                    if (errno == EAGAIN)
                                                    {
                                                        printf("recv() timed out.\n");
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        fprintf(stderr, "recv() failed due to errno = %d\n", errno);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                printf("Ok received from server!\n");
                                            }
                                        }
```

what to do?
thank you !
nir :)

Comment: Did you mean `perror`? Because `error` (from `error.h`) takes at least 3 arguments. Also, `bzero` is deprecated.

Comment: what compiler you are using?

Comment: vs 12 and when i delete bzero lines the second error is no delete too and the third is turn to 1 unresolved externals

Answer (score 0):

bzero is deprecated, documentation recommends using memset / [ZeroMemory macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366920(v=vs.85).aspx) (assuming you're running on windows) instead.

As for `error()`, can't find any documentation for this function but you **can** use this instead:

```
fputs("File write failed.\n", stderr);
```